# Como inicializar um job só após os outros serem finalizados

Tags: c#, job, hangfire

Tenho o seguinte código

```
 public string ManterRequisicoesComprasJob(string routingKey, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = message.FromJson<HookOutDto>();
            var keys = request.GetKeys();
            var empresa = keys[0];
            var sistema = keys[1].ToInteger();
            var fornecedor = keys[2].ToInteger();
            var negociacao = keys[3];
            var periodo = keys[4].ToInteger();

            return BatchJob.StartNew(batch =>
            {
                var jobId = batch.Enqueue<IHookTargetService>(x => x.Adicionar(null, request.Id, TargetHook.PROCUREMENT));
                jobId = batch.ContinueJobWith<IRequisicaoCompraService>(jobId, x => x.GetGrupoRequisicoes(null, empresa, fornecedor, sistema, periodo, negociacao));
                jobId = batch.ContinueJobWith<IRequisicaoCompraService>(jobId, x => x.ProcessarRequisicoes(null, empresa, fornecedor, request.Id));
            },
              request.GetJobDescription()
          );
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw exception.Failin();
        }
    }
```

No job ProcessarRequisicoes estou dando continuidade no código

```
public async Task<RequisicaoCompraRequest> ProcessarRequisicoes(PerformContext context, string empresa, int fornecedor, long parentId)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = context.GetAntecedentResult<List<ReqFornecSistemaDto>>();
            var jobId = context.BackgroundJob.Id;
            context.SetJobParameter("PROCESSED", jobId);
            var requisicaoJobs = new List<string>();
            BatchJob.Attach(context.GetBatchId(), batch =>
            {
               foreach (var item in result)
                    batch.ContinueJobWith<IRequisicaoCompraService>(jobId, x => x.GetRequisicao(null, empresa, item.Sistema, item.Local, item.Produto)); //duvida

                jobId = batch.ContinueJobWith<IRequisicaoCompraService>(jobId, x => x.GetCachedRequisicoes(null));
                jobId = batch.ContinueJobWith<IRequisicaoCompraService>(jobId, x => x.GetIdFornecedorProcurement(null, empresa, fornecedor));
                jobId = batch.ContinueJobWith<IMapperService>(jobId, x => x.MapFromAntecedentResult(null, typeof(Lar.Procurement.Client.RequisicaoCompra.RequestWrapper), null));
                jobId = batch.ContinueJobWith<IRequisicaoCompraService>(jobId, x => x.Send(null));
                batch.ContinueJobWith<IHookTargetService>(jobId, x => x.AtualizarFinalizado(null, parentId, TargetHook.PROCUREMENT));
            });

            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw exception.LimTargetException(context, TargetHook.PROCUREMENT);
        }
    }
```

Quero processar todos os jobs GetRequisicao e após finalizado todos com sucesso, desejo ir para o próximo job que é o GetCachedRequisicoes.
Se eu fizer da seguinte forma eu até consigo fazer isso, mas o problema é que a execução é sequencial um job após o outro.

```
                   foreach (var item in result)
                    jobId = batch.ContinueJobWith<IRequisicaoCompraService>(jobId, x => x.GetRequisicao(null, empresa, item.Sistema, item.Local, item.Produto));
```

Mas gostaria de executar mais de um job GetRequisicao por vez e somente no final da conclusão de todos, ir para o próximo job GetCachedRequisicoes. Alguém consegue me ajudar?